# How to play an animator's animation from a certain frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I play an animation from the animator from a certain frame?

I have an animation of 100 frames and I would like to play frames 50-100 frames. How do I make this happen?

```
public Animator vertical_head;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        vertical_head.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
        vertical_head.Play("Take 001", 1, framenumber);

    }
```

The above code does not play from frame number 50 but instead from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where and how you get `frameNumber` but I guess you passed in `50`

[Animator.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html):

> normalizedTime    The time offset **between zero and one**.

expects a value between `0` and `1`. So when you passed in `50` it uses `1` instead which is the last frame of the animation → if the clip is looping it will directly start a new loop so it seems like starting at `0`.

In your case you want to start after the half of the clip's length so:

```
vertical_head.Play("Take 001", 1, 0.5f);
```

additionally it seems that your animation is actually on the default layer so you should also use `0` instead of `1` there:

```
vertical_head.Play("Take 001", 0, 0.5f);
```

Comment: Even after this the animation starts from frame 0. Why so? And yes the frameNumber is 50.

Comment: are you sure it is not the default state?

Comment: No it is as i mentioned it

Comment: I didn't see you mentioning that. But in that case you should add an additional empty state e.g. `Idle` and make it the default state. Than using above code should do it .. with the information you provided I don't see why it shouldn't

Comment: Thank you derHugo. What worked is vertical_head.Play("Take 001", 0, 0.5f); 
I guess using 0 instead of 1 did the work.

Comment: well I don't know how your animation layers are setup .. I thought the `1` was intentional but yes .. if you have only the default layer it is `0`